# Dependency injection in angular 1 typescript project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, dependency-injection, jwt

I am trying to use angular-jwt with typescript in my angular1 project. I installed angular-jwt by using

```
typings install dt~angular-jwt --global
```

I have it in the typings>globals>angular-jwt but there is no angular-jwt in the `typings.json` file. Is this a problem?

Also I get and error: Module `ngJwtAuth` is not available! while i try to use it a dependency.

```
import * as angular from 'angular';
import 'angular-jwt';

angular.module('app', ['ngJwtAuth']);
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `ngJwtAuth` module wasn't defined.

Module's name is [`angular-jwt`](https://github.com/auth0/angular-jwt/blob/master/src/angularJwt/angularJwt.js), not `ngJwtAuth`.

The absence of a package in `typings.json` is a problem because it won't be installed for cloned repo. To save the package in `typings.json` [it should be](https://github.com/typings/typings/blob/master/docs/commands.md)

```
typings install dt~angular-jwt --global --save
```